# Dynamically Filter Html Table with 2 filters Jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, html, filter, custom-data-attribute

I have a table of casinos with various data attributes eg

```
<tr data-games='poker, dice' data-payments='visa, cash'></tr>
```

I filter them with a checkbox input that stores a value in an array that gets searched by a regex Map which takes every word in the array and says if this word is in the appropriate Data-attr then show that row.

```
//On Checkbox input add/remove the input to an object
$("#filterDiv .gamesList").delegate("input[type='checkbox']", 'change', function() {
var $this = $(this);
 if ($this.prop('checked')) {
     delete gameBoxes['all'];
     gameBoxes[$this.attr('name')] = $this.val();
    gameFilters+=1;
    }
    else {
        delete gameBoxes[$this.attr('name')];
        gameFilters -=1;
    }

    //Take all checkbox values from object
        Object.values = function(object) {
        var values = [];
            for(var property in object) {
                values.push(object[property]);
                }
        return values;
    }
        var val = Object.values(gameBoxes);

    //hide rows that dont match the regApproved strings
    $(".loading tr").hide().filter(function() {

        var rtnData = "";

        var regApproved=    new RegExp(val.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'), 'i');
            rtnData = (

            $(this).attr("data-games").match(regApproved)
            );


    return rtnData;

    }).fadeIn("fast");

});
```

I'm just wondering on the best way of combining this filter with another.

Im thinking perhaps create a variable eg(gameFilters/payFilters) that goes positive when 1 filter is pressed and then if that var is positive take the regApproved variable from the other filter to also apply to the current one.

Comment: If you convert the `data` attributes to hold serialised array values then you can get rid of the need for Regex, then you can just use `indexOf()`, eg. `data-games="['poker', 'dice']"`. If you require a more complete example of the logic, could you please update the question to include a working example of the filter logic

Comment: This is the code im working with
I cant get it to run on the fiddle but thats the basis of the code
https://jsfiddle.net/zv1w6j9u/1/

Comment: `code $("#filterDiv .gamesList").delegate("input[type='checkbox']", 'change', 
    function(PASS THIS CHECKBOX) {
    do code and if the other filter is cchecked call that filter to
    } `
So i think I have to declare seperate functions and call them when filters are clicked. The problem is it has to pass the values of approved data into each function call and also has to know which element was clicked in the function call>

How would I pass $(this) into the onclick of checkbox function?